# C++ variable arguments using initializer lists

Tags: c++, initializer-list

Assume the following code, which is a tiny sprintf substitute. (The _itoa and the likes was just used to keep the code short.)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
class Arg {
public:
    Arg(const std::string& s) :m_str(s) {}
    Arg(const char* s) : m_str(s) {}
    Arg(int digi, double number)  {char buf[128]; m_str = _gcvt(number, digi, buf);}
    operator const std::string& ()const { return m_str; }
private:
    std::string m_str;
};

class Format {
public:
    Format(/*const char* format, */std::initializer_list<Arg> args); // see below
    const std::string& str()const { return m_str; }
private:
    std::string m_str;
};

Format::Format(/*const char* format, */std::initializer_list<Arg> args) {
    auto arg = args.begin();
    auto format = std::string(*arg++);
    for(const char* c = format.c_str(); *c!='\0'; ++c) {
        if(*c=='%') { m_str+=*arg++; }
        else { m_str+=*c; }
    }
}


int main() {

    std::string test1 = Format{"test Double:% String:%", {5, 456.78}, "foo"}.str();

    // I want to make this work. See the braces.
    std::string test2 = Format("test Double:% String:%", {5, 456.78}, "foo").str();

    return 0;
}
```

You see, I want to pass arguments, limited to type "Arg", but use a constructor that uses e.g. varadic templates instead of the initializer_list<> for better readability.

I tried:

```
    template<typename... T>
    Format(T&& ... args) : Format(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```

But i get:

```
error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Format'
note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::initializer_list` requires `{}` not `()`.

`{5, 456.78}` has no type and couldn't be deduced for template.

The way to keep your syntax in the old overload way:

```
Format(Arg arg0) : Format(std::initializer_list{arg0});
Format(Arg arg0, Arg arg1) : Format({arg0, arg1});
Format(Arg arg0, Arg arg1, Arg arg2) : Format({arg0, arg1, arg2});
// ... Up to some limit
```

Comment: While this seems like a hack, it does exaclty what I want it to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should use braces in member initializer list, to forward to the constructor taking `std::initializer_list`.

```
template<typename... T>
Format(T&& ... args) : Format{std::forward<T>(args)...} {}
//                           ^                        ^
```

Secondly, given `Format("test Double:% String:%", {5, 456.78}, "foo")`, unfortunately braced-init-list like `{5, 456.78}` can't be deduced in template type deduction, it has no type. You can specify the type explicitly like

```
std::string test2 = Format("test Double:% String:%", Arg(5, 456.78), "foo").str();
//                                                      ^         ^
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explaination of "why does this fail" (template deduction).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
template<typename... T>
Format(T&& ... args) : Format({std::forward<T>(args)...}) {}}
```

But in call you should manually point that second argument is `Arg`, like this:

```
std::string test2 = Format("test Double:% String:%", Arg{5, 456.78}, "foo").str();
```

[example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/40FU8bwKWDkNyHhG)